# Transpose columns into rows with first column data repeating using awk

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, gawk

I've the input in test.txt as

```
month,var1,var2
June,10,a
Sep,20,b
Dec,30,c
```

I want the output as

```
month,variable,value
June,var1,10
June,var2,a
Sep,var1,20
Sep,var2,b
Dec,var1,30
Dec,var2,c
```

Note that the number of columns starting from second column is dynamic. It can have 2 columns or 100 columns. How can we transpose the data using awk?

Comment: If an answer provides a satisfactory answer (as seems to be the case), please mark it as accepted by checking the box next to it. A green check mark will tell others that the answer was accepted and can be further exploited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$ awk -F, '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS} 
    NR==1{n = split($0,a); print "month,variable,value"; next}
    {for(i=2;i<4;i++) print $1,a[i],$i}
' file
month,variable,value
June,var1,10
June,var2,a
Sep,var1,20
Sep,var2,b
Dec,var1,30
Dec,var2,c
```

(this is more like exploding than transposition).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The output is close but it doesn't give the exact output. The headers are incorrect. Also, note that I only want 3 columns in the output even if there are 100 columns in the input.

Comment: @SrikanthKondamadugula please see edited answer

Comment: @steeldriver, perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS} 
    NR==1{n = split($0,a); print "month,variable,value"; next}
    {for(i=2;i<NF;i++) if (a[i] !=""){ print $1,a[i],$i} }
' file
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contibution. Your answer looks very much like the accepted answer, so you may want to add some explanation on how yours is different / how that difference improves on the accepted answer.